# Is it bad to delete the question?

Tags: discussion, support, delete

Is it bad to delete a question when it is not answered to a no. of days or the answered suggested are not working and no more answers are coming.

In short I want to say that I have asked some questions but i didn't find any useful answer and they are not active from many days.

Can I delete them ? Will it affect my superuser account or not ?

Comment: Instead of deleting the questions, you should try to improve them. In general, there's nothing to gain from deleting them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, you can delete them if you are no longer interested in an answer. However, I personally would recommend to just leave them up—maybe someone has an answer for you some day.

Deleting your own questions should really be avoided in favor of editing and improving them. Deleting a question that was put on hold or closed negatively affects your account up to the point where it might be banned from further posting questions. Deleting open questions with a zero score will probably not make much of a difference, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: is that zero score means no vote.

Comment: Yes, or votes that result in a total of 0.